# An invalid object handle was used. - Unity Everyplay IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, everyplay

I am seeing following error from everyplay on IOS in my live game. Unfortunately I do not have full detailed logs in my game analytics. There is no stack associated with it.

Error is mapped to unity log handler. Say if you log:
Debug.LogError("An invalid object handle was used.")
It'll come up an error in analytics.

Device:
Apple Iphone OS-7.0.4
Game:
https://itunes.apple.com/app/id890243952

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately with that information is virtually impossible to tell what could be going wrong. Have you been able to reproduce the issue yourself?

Comment: Understood. I am not able to repro the issue myself. If I could, will surely update this thread.